# get different result array from model codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in using Codeigniter as web api, I want to get this result

```
{"result":[{"id":"1","nama":"Orion","nomor":"08576666762"},{"id":"2","nama":"Mars","nomor":"08576666770"},{"id":"7","nama":"Alpha","nomor":"08576666765"}],"success":"1","message":"success"}
```

but instead I get this kind of result :

```
{"result":[[{"id":"1","nama":"Orion","nomor":"08576666762"},{"id":"2","nama":"Mars","nomor":"08576666770"},{"id":"7","nama":"Alpha","nomor":"08576666765"}]],"success":"1","message":"success"}
```

I wonder where am I get it wrong?

I am using codeigniter and my code below is from controller and models

m_server.php (modals)

```
<?php 
    Class M_server extends CI_Model {

        function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->database();
        }

        // buat view dashboard main
        function dash_main1(){
            $data = $this->db->query("

            select *
            from telepon

            ");

            $result = array();
            $result['result'] = array();

            $result['success'] = "1";
            $result['message'] = "success";

            array_push($result['result'], $data->result());

            return $result;
        }
    }
```

Rest_server.php (controller)

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Rest_server extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('m_server');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');

        $this->load->view('rest_server');
    }

    function dash_main1(){

        $data=$this->m_server->dash_main1();
        echo json_encode($data);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line (optional)

```
$result['result'] = array();
```

And change this line

```
$result['result'] = $data->result(); //result become the array
```

`array_push` add an element to an existing array